# Node/mongoose saving complex schema with error doesn't save or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have a complex schema that i am trying to save in mongodb but having problems with it.

```
const itemsSchema =new Schema({
  cat: {type: String, required: true},
  catItems: [{
    items:{type: String},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, default: true}

     }]
  });
module.exports=mongoose.model('CatItem', itemsSchema, 'catitems');
```

Using mongoose I am saving it like this....

```
CatItem.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req._id, 'catItems._id': req.catItems._id}, {$set: {catItems.items: req.catItems.items}, {upsert: true}, (err, catitems) =>{
  If(err) return callback(err);
   return (catitems)
});
```

When I try to save it using above it doesnt save doesnt give any particular error just callback is not a function. If i change callback with res.send again send is not a function. It doesnt even save. Please let me know how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Should not `catItems._ids:` be `"catItems._id":` You seem to have forgotten quotes as well as pluralized a name. Mongoose removes invalid entries that do not match the schema. Same goes for all the keys in `$set`. "dot notation" requires the quotes, and without it it's actually invalid JavaScript.

Comment: I doubt that `findOeAndUPdate` is a function - misspelled?

Comment: sorry for the typos as I had to write the code original is on my office computer which i cant use. Code compiles fine. Its some problem the way i am saving. Specially updating the items. Thanks

Comment: Things don't "silently" happen anywhere. Turn on debugging `mongoose.set('debug',true)` and see what is happening. There are still typos in the question you have not addressed. That's not good. Why can you simply not copy your code? It makes it harder to say what's wrong if we are not looking at the same thing as you actually have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Cannot Update A field of array in nested documents by using set like this:

{$set: {catItems.items: req.catItems.items}

Use instead:

```
{$set: {catItems.0.items: req.catItems.items} for updating the first record of
the array. or instead manipulate in middleware function.
like:
CatItem.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req._id, 'catItems._id': req.catItems._id}, 
(err, catitems)=>{ 
  catItems.items = req.catItems.items;
  catItems.save();
  return (catitems)
});
```